# Не отображается русскоязычный текст latex

Tags: вёрстка, latex

Изучаю latex, но русскоязычный текст выводить не получается.
Код следующий:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
Научная статья — законченное авторское произведение, описывающее результаты оригинального научного исследования (первичная научная статья) или посвящённая рассмотрению ранее опубликованных научных статей, связанных общей темой (обзорная научная статья). В первичных научных статьях авторами излагается существенная информация о проведённом исследовании в форме, позволяющей другим членам научного сообщества оценить исследование, воспроизвести эксперименты, а также оценить рассуждения и сделанные из них выводы.
\end{document}
```

А в представлении вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что не так делаю.

Comment: Предположение но а если \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} переписать на \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
Если не помогло установите cm-super

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, Вы используете компилятор `xelatex` - он не очень дружит с пакетом `babel` (по крайней мере, я смог так сымитировать эту ошибку).

Решение 1: использовать компилятор `pdflatex` вместо `xelatex`;

```
%pdfLatex (выставите в настройках Вашего редактора)
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
    Научная статья — законченное авторское произведение, описывающее результаты оригинального научного исследования (первичная научная статья) или посвящённая рассмотрению ранее опубликованных научных статей, связанных общей темой (обзорная научная статья). В первичных научных статьях авторами излагается существенная информация о проведённом исследовании в форме, позволяющей другим членам научного сообщества оценить исследование, воспроизвести эксперименты, а также оценить рассуждения и сделанные из них выводы.
\end{document}
```

Решение 2: использовать пакет `polyglossia` вместо `babel`

```
%xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif} %шрифт с кириллицей!

\begin{document}
    Научная статья — законченное авторское произведение, описывающее результаты оригинального научного исследования (первичная научная статья) или посвящённая рассмотрению ранее опубликованных научных статей, связанных общей темой (обзорная научная статья). В первичных научных статьях авторами излагается существенная информация о проведённом исследовании в форме, позволяющей другим членам научного сообщества оценить исследование, воспроизвести эксперименты, а также оценить рассуждения и сделанные из них выводы.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, да все верно, был выставлен в настройках компилятор xelatex, как только сменила на pdflatex, все встало на свои места. Текст корректно отображается.